# Prevent skipping video on Azure Media Player

Tags: azure-media-player

How can we prevent skipping the video on Azure Media Player? I have tried many tricks to do it but got failed every time.

Below are the events which I have tried:

```
amp.eventName.seeking
amp.eventName.play
amp.eventName.playing
amp.eventName.pause
amp.eventName.ended
amp.eventName.timeupdate
```

In which there is no option to prevent skipping the video.